# Looking for a better way to demo iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Any suggestions on how to demonstrate iPhone apps on a desktop better?

Currently:  I'm passing out xcode projects to marketing people and of course with that comes configuration issues, support, etc.

They are then using the simulator + WebEx to do demos.

Only option I currently see is to Jailbreak + ScreenSplitr (more support headaches)....and yes it needs to be iPhone, not Android.

Thanks

Comment: You need specifically a live demo? There's a way to shoot a video from the simulator screen.

Comment: you can copy the binary from the simulator directory .. they won't need the xcode project at all

Answer (score 3):

If they have the iOS simulator installed then you can transfer the app directly to another simulator.

Each app is in a folder in the `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ios version/Applications/SomeGUID` where the ios version is whatever ios version they built the app for and the SomeGUID is a unique identifier that gets assigned at build time. You will have to go in to each one and figure out which one is your build before sending it. But all you need to do is zip that folder with the guid name and put that in someone elses simulator folder and it will show up in the simulator's springboard.

Comment: This worked well on Snow Leopard, thanks.

For Lion users, you can get to the library via terminal.  It's hidden by default now.

Answer (score 1):

as you have already achieved the hard part and people have xcode installed take a look at simulator launcher

Simulator Launcher https://github.com/landonf/simlaunch/

> Simulator Launcher builds custom executables to automatically launch an
>   embedded iPhone Simulator application using the correct iPhone SDK.

To use, drag any iPhone Simulator binary onto the "Simulator Builder"
application. This will create a new Mac OS X application that bundles
and launches your iPhone Simulator application from within Mac OS X. The
new application's icon and name will be derived from your iPhone Simulator
application.

The built launcher will:
- Detect all installed iPhone SDKs (such as the beta iPad SDK) using Spotlight,
  even if they're in non-standard locations
- Automatically select the best available SDK for your application.
- Install and launch your application in the appropriate Simulator.
- Works with both iPhone and iPad simulator binaries.